# Flask + Flask-SocketIO return 404 for route when requesting from Ionic client

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, flask-socketio

I am working on a real-time chatting and photo sharing application. I use Flask as my server side to build RESTful web services and use Ionic framework (AngularJS) to build my client on mobile.

I have a web service endpoint [GET] /feeds/user_id which returns new feeds of a user. When I use the following line of code to initialize my app, I can correctly retrieve data from both localhost and my application running on mobile.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

As I build the app with real-time chat, I use Flask-SocketIO and I change the way to initialize my app to the one below, as specified in the official documentation.

```
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', policy_server=False)
```

However, I cannot retrieve data from my mobile app now with the above way of initialization. One of the sample log is:

```
192.168.1.100 - - [2015-09-13 23:38:32] "GET http://192.168.1.101:5000/feeds/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.002000
```

However, I am able to retrieve data from my localhost and another machine in the same network using the same link, so I am sure the server is listening to all public IPs. I have also disabled my firewall.

My code snippet below:

```
from app import socketio, app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', policy_server=False)
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Update**: When I only use app.run(), the log is as below:

```
192.168.1.110 - - [20/Sep/2015 00:17:23] "GET http://192.168.1.103:5000/feeds/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

As Miguel mentioned, this is a weird log but it works, so thanks to the robustness of Flask!

I also tried to run my app on iOS, which works perfectly fine. Now I suspect it is an issue of Ionic framework on Android platform, or just on my device. My device is Nexus 7 Gen 1, running Android 5.1.1.

Comment: The log snippet that you show is odd. For a normal request, the scheme server and port should not appear in the log. I would have expected to see `"GET /feeds/1"` instead of `"GET http://192.168.1.101:5000/feeds/1"`. Does your working client generate the same log?

Comment: @Miguel I remember when I hit the link from within browser, I get `"GET /feeds/1"` always. If I hit the link from my app, it always shows the server and port, but it only works when I use `app.run()`. I will confirm this again when I run my code later.

Comment: I think your code must be sending a bad URL, which Flask cannot parse correctly.

Comment: @Miguel yes I think you are correct - my updates above. It looks like an Ionic issue than Flask issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem myself.

Flask and Flask-SocketIO does not start the same type of server - Flask starts standard Werkzeug development web server, but Flask-SocketIO starts gevent web server. That's why I see the different behaviours as I mentioned in the question, but the problem is not with Flask.

The real problem lies in how the built-in WebView handles the HTTP requests to server side. In my device, it seems that the WebView handles the requests in a strange way - I did not look into this in detail. As a result of this, the gevent web server is not able to handle this HTTP request - resulting in 404.

The way I solved this is by packaging the WebView of latest Chrome version into my app. I do it using Crosswalk. It perfectly resolved my problem.